# What are the requirements for the acceptance of a hadith from a narrator?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal

I know that there are requirements that those who collected *ahadith* like Bukhari and others to ensure the authenticity of a hadith and accept it.  For example, I hear often that the one giving the hadith must be trustworthy without ever having lied before, or that they must have good *adab*.

For example,

- I once heard a story where Imam Bukhari went to collect a hadith from a man, and when he got to this man's house, he saw that the man's donkey won't come to him.  So what the man did was pick up his clothes and pretend that there was food in it to trick the donkey into coming.  So Imam Bukhari got back on his horse and left without accepting a hadith from this man.
- I have also heard that those who collect hadith would not accept it from a person who stood up while drinking and eating, as they considered this to be bad manners.

So what I would like to know is, **what are the requirements that allowed the collector of *ahadith* (e.g. Bukhari) to accept a hadith from any person?** I would like an answer that is detailed.

Comment: I think this is discussed in what is called [علم الرجال](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%84) [biographical evaluations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biographical_evaluation)

Comment: @Kaveh It is, but different scholars of Hadith vary, some may have strict requirements, while others are more loose.  My question is specifically asking for the requirements of a scholar like Bukari.

Answer (score 2):

**These are the four fundamental requirements of "rawy el hadith":**

1. Puberty, a narration is never accepted from a child who has not reached puberty.
2. Good memory and he must be able to differentiate between right and wrong.
3. He must be "saleh" (good man and knows his religion well) and not "fasek".
4. As you have mentioned already "be trustworthy and not have lied before".

As for blind men and slaves: their testimony in hadith was forbidden by Imam Shafe'y but allowed by Imam Malek. But reports are accepted from them.

As for women reports are not accepted from them, however there are 2 exceptions and they are A'esha and Ome-Salama

[الحاوي الكبير في فقه مذهب الإمام الشافعي](http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=94&ID=8611)

Comment: I am very happy you answered, I do know that a Hadith is accepted from a child when he/she can tell between a donkey and a horse, and that is usually age 7.  As for the acceptance of Hadith as forbidden, makes no sense, and that would make all the authentic Ahadith narrated by women other tha A'ishah and Um Salama inauthentic.  Please provide citations to back up your answer and make it stronger.  And also I would like to mention that my question asks for all of the requirements not the fundamentals.  Thank you.

Comment: this is a reference :http://www.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=94&ID=8611

Comment: i think these are all , do you want the requirements of a narration teller or the requirements for a narration to be accepted as correct "sahyh"?

Comment: I will like the requirements of the narration teller, which you have given.  But it would be nice if you also add other views, like if it were views from Imam Bukari if possible.

Comment: Dear you should read sahih bukharis introduction a detailed answer about your question is written there and bukhari's views are about why he did collect some and neglect some

Comment: أولها (الصحيح) وهو ماأتصل....إسناده ولم يشذ أو يعل
Sahyh is a hadith with a clear line (sanad) without interruption and without any weaknesses 
يرويه عدل ضابط عن مثله.... معتمد في ضبطه ونقله Narrated by someone with good memory and reputation from an other whos memory and reputation (thrustworthy) is known. You should add Islam to your 5 Points as a non muslim can't be a rawy!

Comment: The **exceptions for woman are wrong** there are many ahadith narrated by female sahaba not only the mothers of believers. Ibn hajjar al-'Asqalani even named 824 women who lived until the 3rd century and were known to be a rawy of hadith -in fact his wife was a student if his teacher al-Hafidh al-'Iraqi too-! See also [Wikipedia -Arabic-](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D9%8A)

Answer (score 2):

**The surveying of the authenticity of a hadith (tradition) is related to the Elm-al-Rejal and  Mostalehul-Hadith.**

In the science of Rejal (Elme-Rejal),  it is discussed one by one of it in accordance with the:

> 1: Islam
>
> 2: Edalah (justice)
>
> 3: puberty
>
> 4: faith(Iman)
>
> 5: intellect(Aql)
>
> And likewise other items and the document of the narration will be
>   specified in accordance with the result (as the right hadith,
>   authentic, goodness, or even weak ...

**Researchers of the narrators says that there are four general conditions as the conditions of Hadith acceptance (in a specific step of it):**

> 1: comparison or dis-opposition with the book of Allah
>
> 2: agreement or dis-opposition (no-opposition) with Nesbiat-al-Qat’ee
>
> 3: agreement or dis-opposition with rational reasons
>
> 4: dis-opposition with the items that Imamiah have Ijma’ and Itifaq.

(Note: Of course It was not a complete answer,  since you inquired a very significant question which needs a long answer (I think).  But briefly I mentioned some of its important pars as far as I could, hopefully it be profitable for you)

**Reference:**

- [www.hadith.net](http://www.hadith.net/n685-e6480.html)

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any official ones given by the Prophet or Companions. Omar Bin Alkhattab almost started to collect the hadiths but then thought of it as a bad idea and reverted, probably for the same reason why many give Hadith the same level as Quran at times, if not more.

The first person who ordered the collection of Hadith was Caliphate Omar Ben Abdel Aziz. He ordered Abu Bakir Ben Alhazam, to record ALL hadiths from the scholars. From there are came many more who organized and authenticated these hadiths solely based on their opinions.

There is a general rule, it is not much of a rule, but common sense where the person who is reporting from another person to have lived during their times and actually met.